# How can I change boolean_button terminology?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have defined a button with the `boolean_button` widget

```xml
<button name="toggle_enable" type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-unlink">
    <field name="enabled" widget="boolean_button" options='{"terminology": "active"}'/>
</button>
```

I've tried to change the terminology to **Exported / Not exported** but I have not succeeded. Can someone tell me if it is possible to define a new terminology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Odoo v10, you can do it as following :

```xml
<div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
    <button name="toggle_active" type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-check-square" >
        <field name="active" widget="boolean_button" options='{"terminology": {
            "string_true": "Production Environment",
            "hover_true": "Switch to test environment",
            "string_false": "Test Environment",
            "hover_false": "Switch to production environment"
        }}'/>
    </button>
</div>
```

But in Odoo v9, by default it is not there.